# What causes a unit separator to be appended to a string during XML parsing?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

[clean string from 'unit separator' (0x1f) character for xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107888/clean-string-from-unit-separator-0x1f-character-for-xml)

I'm facing a very similar issue as posted in the above link.
I understand that unit separator has to be sanitized / stripped off from the attributes during XML parsing.

However I'd like to understand the specific root-cause.

In my case, when a particular text field is given "11010191_Eb03", during XML parsing phase of the same at activation the "unit separator character" seems to appear in between "b" and "0" in the above mentioned value. Could someone please help me understand why is it happening in this space so that this could be handled better?

[terminal debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84pcV.png)

Comment: Is it present on XML as `&#x241F;`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added an image hyperlinked as "terminal debug" in the post